# Hololens 2: How to programmatically clear the down direction in Moving Platform Mode?

Tags: c#, hololens

I want to clear the gravity's down direction(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens2-moving-platform) programmatically through the app in C#. I am not able to find the relevant APIs. (note: there are apis for enabling/disabling the moving platform mode as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unity/moving-platform-unity ).

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Currently, this SDK does not provide this function, you can send a request through [Feedback Hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens-feedback).

Comment: Thanks Wang. I think I can estimate down vector with averaging in research mode. Is there a way to estimate the down vector that hololens is using.

Comment: I notice that there are OMA-URI( ./Device/Vendor/MSFT/Policy/Config/MixedReality/ManualDownDirectionDisabled ) for changing these settings. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens2-moving-platform . Is there a way to modify them programmatically in C#.

Comment: Referring to [ManualDownDirectionDisabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/policy-csp-mixedreality#mixedreality-manualdowndirectiondisabled), this Policy refers to whether the user can manually change the down direction. It is allowed by default, that is, the method in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/hololens/hololens2-moving-platform#manually-set-down-direction. This Policy cannot be modified programmatically, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/mem/intune/deploy-oma-uris-to-target-csp-via-intune to learn more.